Baking bump map into texture with normal map
I'm trying to bake a bump map from procedural materials into a texture so I can export to .fbx, but no matter what i do I'm not getting the intended result when I plug the generated texture into my BSDF. My other bump maps work after baking, but not the edge around the rectangle. How would I go about making this bump map exportable?




I was able to bake it here and use it, but it was necessary to "save" the baked image first:

Then in the "Image texture" node, you take the image from the file.
Since your "Image texture" doesn't have a file extension there, I guess you didn't save the image?

That would be true for generated textures (such as the brick in the question - if it weren't plugged into a UV). But for images textures, as explained on the manual: "If [the vector input is] left unconnected, the coordinate is taken from the object’s active UV map (with Z = 0)."

Normal map vs bump map
Is there a particular reason why you turned your bump data into a normal map? Bump is an elevation data, normal map is an orientation data, so I wouldn't expect to get an equal result from each other.
To illustrate, I did a mockup of your scene: made a brick texture, plugged into a bump node, then into a Principled BSDF, then baked that as a normal map, and mixed the two half-and-half from left to right plugged as emission to see them "raw":

We can see the normal data from the bump on the left is very different from the normal data from the normal map on the right.
Baking data
Comparing your gird pattern before and after baking:

To me, it looks like the normal map works "as excepted": pixels get shaded as if the face they represent is oriented differently than it really is - creating the impression of a bent surface.
But it's the light gray color that we really miss out.
Your original shader uses varying data only on the Principled's base color and normal inputs, so they are the only ones that "need baking" (a single value is enough for the rest, no need to bloat the memory with pure single color images).
To bake the Base Color, you can use the Diffuse bake type with only the Color influence enabled:

For the bump, there isn't a specific bake type for that. A way around is to plug your brick node into your Material Output node's Surface socket (or ⎈ Ctrl LMB your brick node if you use the Node Wrangler addon, which is recommended):

Then use the Emit bake type (any color data plugged in the material's surface output is read as if plugged in an Emission shader, which is shadeless and neutral and baked with the Emit bake type).

???? - Isn't that what the bump node does? Transform bumps into normals?

I'm no expert, AFAIK both normal map node and bump node output normal data, but their source is not from the same "point of view" so to say. Bump is from an elevation data, normal map is an orientation. To give you an idea of the difference in data you get from what we see in the question, here's a mockup of it, but showing the normal data we obtain from the bump on the left vs from the "bump baked into normal map" on the right. Unless I'm wrong somewhere in the process.

After taking your comments into consideration, I noticed that we need to "save" the baked image first, for later use it in a texture with the "non-color" space. Then your mockup will show "almost" the same thing for both. (I guess the difference might be because of the extrusion value given in the bake, or maybe the low res I used). That said, I was able to succesfully bake and see the results properly. So I have no idea where in the process the OP failed.

The reason I turned my bump data into a normal map is that I'm trying to turn my data into image textures so I can then export the full model into a .fbx - I'm at least reasonably sure that this is necessary. your answer does help me understand where I've gone wrong but I'm not quite sure how to make the bump data exportable still, as i would prefer to have the bevel in the front panel done by normal maps

@hirtenstar , your bump has absolutely no problem. If you bake, remember to "save" the image (this is a manual operation that you must do) and then plug the image file into a texture node, with "non-color", it will work. I did the tests. If you don't save the image, the result will be the one Lauloque showed, but if you save, you will get a good result. The problem is "not" the bump. The bump node converts bumps into normals.

you can just bake the bump map just as I explained in my answer, no need to bake it "as" another kind of data. At the end it's just an image file.
